# NextJS passing a variable to the frontend script

Tags: next.js, web-frontend

I'm trying to pass the user email (or display name) or whatever to a script in NextJS.

The ultimate reason is to track conversion events.

here's an example with the user email:

```
  const userEmail = useEmail();

  console.log({userEmail});

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Head>
        <title key="title">
          Onboarding {userEmail}| {configuration.site.siteName}
        </title>
      </Head>
      <Script
        id="gr-event"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `console.log('${userEmail}')`,
        }}
      />
```

and yeah, what is most annoying, calling it above the return and in the title tag works fine. But it doesn't work in that script.

I'm a noob and just starting and learning myself, but couldn't find the answer on this one. I tried stringifying it, passing it as a template literal, useEffect, and even a part of a set. Nothing worked.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

figured it out eventually by rerendering the script with email conditional (mind you the email was always there, but this works)

```
{userEmail && (
            <Script
                id="gr-event"
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: `console.log('${userEmail}')`,
                }}
            />
        )}
```

of course I'm not sure if this is the right way to do and if it can bug out.

other solutions are welcomed! thanks!